# How to get JSON data from Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions

Is there something wrong in my code? I always get the error **Error: could not handle the request**. Here's the code of my Cloud Function:

```
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    cors(request, response, () => {
        response.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET");
        response.set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
        response.set("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");

        let dock = [];
        const snapshot = db.collection("users").get()
        snapshot.docs.forEach((val) => {
            dock.push(val.id);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you take a look into your log file in your firebase console under functions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are trying to return `dock` as response, but if you do, try this out:

```
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    cors(request, response, () => {
        response.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET");
        response.set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
        response.set("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");

        let dock = [];
        db.collection("users").get().then(snapshot => {
          snapshot.docs.forEach((val) => {
            dock.push(val.id);
          });
          return dock;
        })
        .catch(errors => {
          console.log(errors);
          return false;
        })
    });
});
```

The `get()` returns a promise that you have to solve. 
Also it is a good idea to put a `catch()` at the end to see errors appear, when executing your code.

Answer (score 0):

A HTTPS triggered Cloud Functions (like the one in your question) runs until it sends a response to the client, or until it times out. Since your code never sends a response to the client, it times out. And that's why the client gives you and error.

I assume you want to send the document IDs back to the client, so that'd be something like:

```
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    cors(request, response, () => {
        response.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET");
        response.set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
        response.set("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");

        let documentIds = [];
        db.collection("users").get().then((snapshot) => {
          snapshot.docs.forEach((document) => {
            documentIds.push(document.id);
          });
          res.send(JSON.stringify(documentIDs));
        });
    });
});
```